# ¿Cómo convertir nullable int a int?

Tags: c#, .net

¿Cómo puedo convertir una variable `int?`en `int` en C#?

Tengo dos variables:

```
int? idObjeto = function();
int idNoNull = idObjeto; //<-- Argumento 1 no se puede convertir de int? a int
```

La cosa es que al intentar asignar el valor me da el error indicado *"Argumento 1 no se puede convertir de `int?` a `int`"*

Comment: Si no me equivoco, sucede porque `Int32` es **value type** y no **reference type**, es decir, su valor por defecto nunca es `null`, sino es `0`. C# nos da la oportunidad de tener *nullable value types*, es decir `int?`, que, a como reportas, no es lo mismo que `int`. Si lo que quieres es asignarle el **valor** de la variable `idObjeto` a `idNoNull`, entonces, lo que tienes que hacer es `int idNoNull = idObjeto.Value;` PERO, cabe mencionar que no es una *conversión*, como lo pides en la pregunta.

Comment: @Arriel ¿usar .Value no puede provocar una excepción en algún caso?  Al final encontré la función `GetValueOrDefault();`

Comment: Estás en lo correcto. Usar `.Value` puede provocar una excepción si no evalúas si existe valor o no. Los nullable type también tienen una propiedad `bool HasValue`, que te dice si el valor existe. El método `GetValueOrDefault();` es la unificación de todo esto. Verifica si trae un valor, si lo trae, lo devuelve, en caso contrario, devuelve el **default para el tipo de dato**. Tu respuesta es la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al final encontré que existe la función `GetValueOrDefault`, que devuelve o bien el valor, o bien el default, en este caso 0.

```
int? idObjeto = function();
int idNoNull = idObjeto.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Otra forma que he visto y que a primera vista parece más óptima es:

```
int idNoNull = idObjeto ?? default(int);
```

Esto comprueba idObjeto y en caso de ser null devuelve el valor por defecto de int.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar esta instrucción aunque si es nulo producirá excepción

```
int idNoNull = (int) idObjeto;
```

Por ello te recomiendo que primero compruebes si tiene valor y si es así se lo asignes:

```
int idNoNull2 =idObjeto.HasValue?  idObjeto.Value : 0;
```